# ¿Como limitar el numero que se ingresa en un input con respecto a otra variable numerica?

Tags: javascript, html, input

Necesito validar el input de la cantidad de productos que el usuario va a añadir a su compra con respecto a la cantidad de stock que hay disponible en el momento.

```
@foreach($cartCollection as $item)
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $item->quantity }}" id="quantity" name="quantity" maximo="{{$item->attributes->stock}}" onkeyup="myFunction({{$item->id}})">
/**lo tengo que validar con respecto a esta variable--->{{$item->attributes->stock}}**/
@endforeach
```

Quisiera poder validarlo por medio de javascript pero no se me ocurre como hacerlo, la idea es que si hay 20 productos en stock el usuario pueda ingresar un numero del 1 al 20, y no permitir que sea mayor a ese rango. Tengo algo como esto pero aun no logro hacerlo funcionar....

```
    function myFunction(numero) {
   var div1 = document.getElementById("quantity"+numero);
   var maximo = div1.getAttribute("maximo");
   var value = document.getElementById("quantity"+numero).value;
   var minimo = 0;

   if( parseInt(value) > parseInt(maximo) ){
       document.getElementById("quantity"+numero).value='';
       document.getElementById("mensaje"+numero).innerHTML='solo hay '+maximo;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("mensaje").innerHTML='';
    }
   }
```

Comment: ¿Que sistema de plantillas o framework estas usando?  Deberias ponerlo en las etiquetas al menos, si te parece bien, para que los demas sepamos tu entorno real

Comment: php y laravel, ahi edite en las etiquetas..

Comment: modifica los `getelementID` por `getElementById` que es la sintaxis correcta de la función a ver si asi te va

Comment: aparte de eso, podrias  poner ese input a la escucha con `addEventListener` y cuando teclee pasarle esa función valid() acondicionada para lo que pretendes, o bien, si sabes el stock, forzarle los atributos `min="0" max="20"` al elemento input directamente o bien mediante javascript tambien

Comment: eso es lo que me estaria faltando creo, porque como esta no realiza nada, como lo pongo a la escucha?

Comment: Primero lo asignas a una variable para que sea más cómodo despues así:  `quantity=document.getElementById('quantity');` y despues lo pones a la escucha así:  `quantity.addEventListener("input", function(){valid()}, false);)` (mas o menos, es para que te hagas a la idea.. o le metes la funcion ahi dentro directamente en lugar del `valid()`

Comment: Y conforme vaya tecleando se irá ejecutando la funcion que le hayas puesto

Comment: Gracias, voy a intentarlo de esa manera a ver si funciona!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero  esto te pueda servir

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <body>

     @foreach($cartCollection as $key=>$item)
        <input type="text" id="fname{{ $key}}" maximo="{{ $item->quantity }}" onkeyup="myFunction({{ $key}})">
     @endforeach

 <p id='mensaje'></p>
 <script>
    function myFunction(num) {
      var div1 = document.getElementById("fname"+num);
      var maximo = div1.getAttribute("maximo");
      var value = document.getElementById("fname"+num).value;
      var minimo = 0;

       if( parseInt(value) > parseInt(maximo) ){          
         document.getElementById("fname"+num).value='';
         document.getElementById("mensaje").innerHTML='Numero excede el limite '+maximo;
       }
       else{
         document.getElementById("mensaje").innerHTML='Numero valido';
       }

     }
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Ejemplo**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
      <?php
      for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) { $stock=$i+20;
          echo "Input ".$i." <input type='text' id='quantity".$i."' maximo='".$stock."' onkeyup='myFunction(".$i.")'><br>";
      }
      ?>
   <p id='mensaje'></p>
   <script>
      function myFunction(numero) {
        var div1 = document.getElementById("quantity"+numero);
        var maximo = div1.getAttribute("maximo");
        var value = document.getElementById("quantity"+numero).value;
        var minimo = 0;
         if( parseInt(value) > parseInt(maximo) ){          
           document.getElementById("quantity"+numero).value='';
           document.getElementById("mensaje").innerHTML='Numero excede el limite '+maximo;
         }
         else{
           document.getElementById("mensaje").innerHTML='Numero valido';
         }
       }
    </script>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: El atributo `maximo` no existe.  Es `max`

Comment: el atributo max no se puede poner en un input de type=text lo cual es un atributo propio la que muestra @masterguru si revisas mas a fondo las propiedades de para html  veras que puedes crear atributos a tu propio criterio esto con el fin de hacer uso como en esta circunstancia, existen  atributos ya definidos como por ejemplo class, max, min, id, value, etc... en este caso yo le asigne uno con el nombre máximo con el fin de poder identificarlo yo abria podido haber puesto limite, mayor, etc eso ya dependiendo de como puedas identificar tus valores.

Comment: Vale, no me fijé en ello, solo vi que el OP preguntaba sobre este input de tipo number:  `<input type="number" ` y por eso lo decia, pues el `max` ya es propio de ese tipo, al igual que el `min`.  No veo la necesidad de reinventar la rueda, pero entiendo tu respuesta ahora.

Comment: estoy de acuerdo en utilizar **max** y  **min** pero lo que no puedes controlar en ese tipo de dato es la introducción manual del valor por ello propuse una solución la cual valide también dicho campo creo que podría ser útil

Comment: No lo dudo, mi comentario inicial sobre el `maximo` fue debido a mi error de interpretación sobre el tipo de input del cual hablabas, esta claro que sabias lo que decias. Y si funciona entonces es una respuesta válida. Aunque discrepo en que con el otro tipo de campo no se pueda controlar su introducción manual, para eso le sugerí addEventListener en los comentarios de la pregunta.

Comment: Hola gente!!! me sirvio el codigo que me paso @Danny me realiza correctamente la validacion una vez excede el stock... muchas gracias, va por ahi compañeros ! :)

Comment: Gente tengo un inconveniente ya que me funciona el codigo, pero cuando existe mas de 1 producto no realiza la validacion en los demas, solo en el primero que agrego al carro, algun consejo para eso?

Comment: deberías darle un identificador único a cada input ya que al entrar en un foreach todos obtienen el mismo identificador usado en la función, voy a modificar mi respuesta corrigiendo ese detalle como creo que debería ser, nos comentas que tal te fue

Comment: Hola danny! al final no me funciona lo que hace javascript una vez que coloco los $key esos que me dijiste, no entiendo porque en la function pusiste la variable "num" no se de donde salio esa.. si saco los keys si funciona pero solamente en el 1er objeto como les habia dicho anteriormente.. Fijate en mi respuesta que la modifique, ahi estan las variables que yo utilizo

Comment: Hola @SneekyFromGondor, bueno la idea con el $key es poder darle un id único a cada input  por ejemplo tenderas  **id='quantity1'** , **id='quantity2'** , **id='quantity3'** posterior a eso estamos enviándole el valor $key a la función onkeyup, con respecto a la variable **num**  es simplemente un parámetro que la función recibe puede tener el nombre que decaes a mi se me ocurrió ponerle num cada quien tiene el criterio libre de nombrarlo lo importante si es que dentro la función deberás hacer uso del mismo..   Adjuntare un ejemplo funcional, nos comentas cualquier otra duda, saludos!

Comment: Hola @Danny ! muchas gracias por seguir estando ahi, ya pude resolver el inconveniente... me sirvieron mucho tus consejos, te agradezco de corazon =)